# Make Notice Board Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a notice board for the user in android studio. Admin makes notice for user and User can able to see the notice. How can I do that? there is two activity one for Admin and the Second for users. there will be a firebase for the data store.

**Note: It will be java based project**

Answer (score 1):

1)Write Frontend part

2)Write Backend part

3)Don't forget to write the logic to connect to the db with your backend

4)Most importantly, read the rules of SO before posting anything like this